# POST receives unknown parameter name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

A regular MVC controller receives a POST where the name of the parameter will have an unknow name, that is, the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFiles(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // Do whatever is needed
}
```

Receives a `HttpPostedFileBase` with a `Guid` as name, that obviously changes at every `POST` not, a parameter called "file", thus being always null.

How can I receive this unknown named `HttpPostedFileBase`?

Comment: Try with `Request.Files` ?

Comment: @Adriani6, I just tryed, as you suggested, but it returned an obeject whi an empty content...

Comment: @Adriani6, it actually did work!!! I misused it in the begining.
If you wish, post as an answer so that I can acknowledge you and we leave it documented...

Comment: Done, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request.Files` contains a collection of files uploaded by the client.

To get all the file names that were uploaded you would do:

`Request.Files.AllKeys`

Or you could just iterate over the collection to do something with each file.

[Documentation can be found here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.files?view=netframework-4.7.2)